# Compile source iOS dependencies for react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

The library I want to link has the sources I want to compile in this folder https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast/tree/master/ios/RNGoogleCast. They lack a tool for auto linking and it the README.md has not lead me to a working app. I also took a look on [the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html). They state that every dependency may have its own `.xcodeproj` file inside, however this is not the case.

Can I build such file from the linked source? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have CocoaPods installed: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

All you need to do is add those two files to your Xcode project. It's the same process as adding an .xcodeproj without having to `Link Binary`, but instead, you add both of those files to your Xcode project on the left toolbar.

Then in your `ios` folder of your app for example, `/myapp/ios/`, you create a file called `Podfile`, and inside it put `pod 'google-cast-sdk`. Then in your terminal in the `/myapp/ios` folder, type `pod install`. This is going to install the library. Once you've done that, from now on you have to open your Xcode project by opening the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj`. You will see this instruction after you've finished installing the Pod. Then just hit the play button.